# Error installing oracle-java8-installer from webup8team ppa

Tags: java, jdk, oracle

Does anyone know how to fix this?

First I did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Then I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  antlr3 libdb6.0 libdb6.0-java-jni libice-dev
  libjakarta-taglibs-standard-java libjnr-netdb-java libjstl1.1-java
  liblivetribe-jsr223-java libpthread-stubs0-dev libsm-dev
  libstringtemplate-java libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev
  libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev wine-compholio wine-compholio-amd64
  wine-compholio-i386:i386 x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input-dev
  x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    The file is already fully retrieved; nothing to do.

Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-8u25-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
 oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java8-set-default
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: sorry if it's hard to read

Comment: well Java fixed it so now it works fine other than a few bugs but i don't care as long as it works

Comment: Did you find a solution or did the problem go away on its own? In the former case, please [write an answer](/help/how-to-answer) and accept it. In the latter case, you should delete your question (otherwise it is going to be closed anyway).

Answer (score 18):

The following might work, it would delete any partials:

```
sudo rm /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-*
```

Then finish the install with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: Edited to make more specific. I can't test against this particular issue, and it doesn't look like the original asker can verify results either.

Comment: AFAIK `dpkg --configure -a` after `apt-get install -f` is redundant.

Comment: In many cases you don't need both. However, I included both as I have run across cases where the first one is not enough and the solution specifically requires the second. This is true especially for installations that were interrupted unexpectedly or that require additional configuring after issues (dependencies, for example) are resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error occur during `sudo apt-get upgrade` behind a corporate proxy. To fix, I edited `/etc/apt/apt.conf` and added the following lines:

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://[<proxyUserName>:<proxyPass>@]<proxyUrl>:<proxyPort>";
Acquire::https::Proxy "http://[<proxyUserName>:<proxyPass>@]<proxyUrl>:<proxyPort>";`

Where

- `[<proxyUserName>:<proxyPass>@]` is your optional proxy authentication (don't include this if you don't authenticate)
- `<proxyUserName>` is your proxy user name
- `<proxyPass>` is your proxy password
- `<proxyUrl>` is your proxy url
- `<proxyPort>` is your proxy port

The oracle tarball is downloaded over https, so if you are behind a proxy apt needs an https proxy to execute it.

After editing, save the file, then open a new terminal. `sudo apt-get update` and install as needed.

Comment: Confirmed, this was the solution for me. I run an apt-proxy locally, and disabling it briefly resolved it.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problems when my Ubuntu system couldn't download file from oracle server (file `jdk-8u111-linux-x64.tar.gz`). So I was have to download it from oracle site ( http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html ) and copy to folder `/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/` manually. This solved the problem and oracle-java8-installer became able to finish the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue I found this as a solution that worked for me:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/oracle-java8-installer.postinst -f
sudo dpkg --configure oracle-java8-installer
```

[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587635/dpkg-error-processing-package-oracle-java8-installer-configure)
[LINK 2](http://www.toontricks.com/2017/11/ubuntu-installation-error-oracle-java8.html)

Answer (score 0):

See this answer [stackoverflow.com/questions/43587635/dpkg-error-processing-package-oracle-java8-installer-configure/48332346#48332346](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587635/dpkg-error-processing-package-oracle-java8-installer-configure/48332346#48332346) for a more detailed explanation why and how to fix it.