# Error while setting up jdk8 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: software-installation, ppa

i was trying to setup jdk 8 using [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html)  guide.
After downloading the jdk i got an error that asked me to manually configure dpkg.

```
adeen-s@adeen-s-PC:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u66+8u65arm-1~webupd8~1) ...
Installing from local file /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-8u66-linux-x64.tar.gz
Removing outdated cached downloads...
mv: cannot move ‘jdk1.8.0_66’ to ‘java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_66’: Directory not empty
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
 oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java8-set-default
```

How do i fix this ?

UPDATE : Tried installing again after following @A.B. 's advice.
here's the output -->

> 2015-11-25 17:56:08 (50.3 KB/s) - ‘jdk-8u66-linux-x64.tar.gz’ saved [181287376/181287376]
>
> Download done.
>   Removing outdated cached downloads...
>   install: cannot stat ‘javaws-wrapper.sh’: No such file or directory
>   dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
>    oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
>     Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
>    dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    oracle-java8-installer
>    oracle-java8-set-default

UPDATE : Output after sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer

```
adeen-s@adeen-s-PC:~$ sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  oracle-java8-installer* oracle-java8-set-default*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 542 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 167 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 165086 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing oracle-java8-set-default (8u66+8u65arm-1~webupd8~1) ...
Purging configuration files for oracle-java8-set-default (8u66+8u65arm-1~webupd8~1) ...
Removing oracle-java8-installer (8u66+8u65arm-1~webupd8~1) ...
Purging configuration files for oracle-java8-installer (8u66+8u65arm-1~webupd8~1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
```

Comment: Take a look http://askubuntu.com/questions/572504/error-installing-oracle-java8-installer-from-webup8team-ppa

Comment: @BeGood I tried that but received a similar error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have used both possibilities to install Oracle Java

Delete the folder and start the installation again:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_66

sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

After that

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

Either you use the PPA or the installation with an archive. But not both.

Comment: Not sure if that's the case because I already had removed the other installation files. Edit : I am trying those steps again and the download has started.

Comment: Tried the steps and posted the output in the question as edit.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install -f` and again `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Comment: @ A.B. got it. But it still does not work for me. same error on the ` sudo apt-get install -f  ` command

Comment: What is the output of `stat /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/javaws-wrapper.sh`

Comment: stat: cannot stat ‘/var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/javaws-wrapper.sh’: No such file or directory

Comment: Funny, run `sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer` and give me the output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32105/discussion-between-adeen-s-and-a-b).

Comment: in my java is not located the /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jdk1.8.0_66 folder 
then how to remove this
java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

Answer (score 2):

We could recover the file by reverting to a previous JDK version. Seems a dumb solution, but it works.

```
$ cd /var/cache/apt/archives
$ sudo dpkg -i oracle-java8-installer_8u77+8u77arm-1~webupd8~1_all.deb
```