# Java Issue dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, java, oracle

I  tried installing java in following way but I could not installed it properly. Below is what it show for the error message:

```
bsaitechnosales@bsaitechnosales:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ sudo apt-get in oracle-java8-installe
download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

For `dpkg`, I tried steps as well and re-tried installing java after `sudo apt-get purge java-oracle8-installer` but still I get the same above error messages. Please advise.

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/status
   56  sudo touch /var/lib/dpkg/status
   57  sudo apt-get update
```

I even followed below mentioned URL but I could not get rid of the above error. Please suggest

[Error while setting up jdk8 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702274/error-while-setting-up-jdk8-on-ubuntu-14-04lts)

Comment: i already followed Cannot install JDK 9 via apt – karel  steps too but that did not work for me. I need some time for further response its because right now i am facing login issue

Comment: I retracted the duplicated flag. Now you have more time to sort this problem out.