# How to install elasticsearch on raspberry pi

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to install `elasticsearch` on Raspberry Pi 3. To do this I am following this [link](https://logz.io/blog/elk-stack-raspberry-pi/) with below steps:

I first install java:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jre
```

Running the above `default-jre` command showed some error so I ran these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge openjdk-8-jre-headless
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

After this, followed below steps:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/share/elasticsearch
cd /usr/share/elasticsearch
wget https://packages.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch
sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

After this when I did `sudo service elasticsearch status` it always shows `Active(exited)`.

How to install elasticsearch on Raspberry pi.?

Thanks

Error while installing `default-jre`

```
Error: missing server JVM at `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk- 
armhf/jre/lib/arm/server/libjvm.so'.
 Please install or use the JRE or JDK that contains these missing components.
 E: /etc/ca-certificates/update.d/jks-keystore exited with code 1.
 done.
 Setting up libatk-wrapper-java (0.33.3-13+deb9u1) ...
 Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-1) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf:
  openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf depends on ca-certificates-java; however:
   Package ca-certificates-java is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-8-jre:armhf:
 openjdk-8-jre:armhf depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless (= 8u162-b12-1~deb9u1); however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package openjdk-8-jre:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libatk-wrapper-java-jni:armhf (0.33.3-13+deb9u1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jre-headless:
 default-jre-headless depends on openjdk-8-jre-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-jre-headless (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icedtea-netx:armhf:
icedtea-netx:armhf depends on openjdk-8-jre; however:
   Package openjdk-8-jre:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package icedtea-netx:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icedtea-8-plugin:armhf:
  icedtea-8-plugin:armhf depends on openjdk-8-jre; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre:armhf is not configured yet.
  icedtea-8-plugin:armhf depends on icedtea-netx (= 1.6.2-3.1); however:
  Package icedtea-netx:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package icedtea-8-plugin:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-jre:
 default-jre depends on default-jre-headless (= 2:1.8-58+b2); however:
  Package default-jre-headless is not configured yet.
 default-jre depends on openjdk-8-jre; however:
  Package openjdk-8-jre:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-jre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of default-java-plugin:
 default-java-plugin depends on default-jre (= 2:1.8-58+b2); however:
  Package default-jre is not configured yet.
 default-java-plugin depends on icedtea-8-plugin; however:
  Package icedtea-8-plugin:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package default-java-plugin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.24-11+deb9u3) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ca-certificates-java
 openjdk-8-jre-headless:armhf
 openjdk-8-jre:armhf
 default-jre-headless
 icedtea-netx:armhf
 icedtea-8-plugin:armhf
 default-jre
  default-java-plugin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What error message did you get after executing _sudo apt-get install default-jre_?

Comment: @masantamaria I have edited the question with the error message.

Comment: Perhaps Java [reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702274/error-while-setting-up-jdk8-on-ubuntu-14-04lts?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) / And alt install instructions to [compare](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java).